# Need Help Understanding Node JS Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Can anyone please help me to understand the syntax error based on the attached screenshot below?

[image: Syntax Error]

My script is supposed to access a given JSON and return the specific value, but somehow it's returning this error.

**Edit 1**

I tested my script with a dummy JSON and the script didn't return any error, so I suspect my original JSON might be giving problem. Here's my JSON.

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "id": "1192199560899293",
      "description": "Hi everyone I have an important announcement to make. So ever since Penny started school, I've been having mixed feelings. \u00a0Besides having a bit of space to myself to breathe and rest my brain/legs, I'm actually a bit bittersweet cos my little baby, who used to sleep at weird hours and gobble puree",
      "title": "Fighter and Penny's new sibling",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2017-04-12T01:17:57+0000"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 109
   },
   "id": "http://fourfeetnine.com/2017/03/05/fighter-and-pennys-new-sibling/"
}
```

**Edit 2**

Here's my script that I run that produces the error.

```
var objects = require('./output.txt');
console.log(objects);
```

`output.txt` is the file that contains the JSON that I pasted in **Edit 1**

Comment: i mean... `function () { {foo:1}` isn't valid javascript. you've got an object just hanging there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: @KevinB I've edited my question to include my original JSON. There's no `function () { {foo:1}` and I don't know how it showed up in the result.

@ÁlvaroGonzález I wanted to create inline plain text but the text were too messy for me to format it properly, so I decided to attach a screenshot instead, but then my reputation isn't high enough for me to attach as a picture instead of an attachment. Thanks for editing my question.

Comment: that json is valid, as you can see by pasting it here: http://jsonlint.com/ so that's probably irrelevant to your question. The error in your screenshot is clearly due to invalid javascript, and not related to json. do you have a new error message?

Comment: @KevinB I've edited my question again to include the script that produces the error. And no, this is the only error message I get. There's no other error message.

Comment: I think Node.js will assume that a file is JavaScript unless its extension is `.json`. Try renaming the file to `output.json` and changing your code to `require('./output')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var objects = require('./output.txt');
```

The `require()` function belongs to the [module loading system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). Despite the name, it can actually load several types of files and directories and not only Node modules. As per the [high-level algorithm in pseudocode](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) shown in docs:

> `require(X)`
>
> If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
>
> a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
>
> [...]
>
> LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
>
> 1. If X is a file, **load X as JavaScript text**.  STOP
> 2. If X.js is a file, load X.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
> 3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP
> 4. If X.node is a file, load X.node as binary addon.  STOP

Since you get **SyntaxError**, output.txt does not contain valid JavaScript code.

If you really want to load JSON, you need to enforce subrule #3 by renaming the file to `output.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jordan suggestion. The fault is indeed due to wrong file extension. After changing the file extension from `.txt` to `.json`, then the syntax error disappeared.